# Use of the word "understanding"

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I was taking an English test, and I couldn't find the wrong sentence. Could you help me out ???

Thank you

**15) All sentences below are correct except**:

A) After understanding the grammar rules it is easier to do exercises, don't you agree?

B) I am sorry, but I am not understanding what you are trying to say

C) It is a matter of understanding each other

D) Understanding grammar is very important

Comment: Which ones look right to you? Do multiple options seem incorrect? Is there a part of the instructional section covered by this test that might apply to this question? It would help a lot to know more specifically about the exact point at which this confuses you and the subject matter it is designed to evaluate.

Comment: There is no context about the question. I can't find the mistake in any of these sentences. For me, all of them are correct. I  would like to know which one is wrong.

Comment: Well, in a way they are all wrong, and in another way they are all fine. That's why it would help to know the context, the nonexistence of which I find very difficult to believe.

Comment: For starters, only one of these sentences has closing punctuation, but it is also the one that doesn't begin with a capital letter. One of them sounds a little awkward because it uses present continuous tense with "understanding" where most people would default to simple present, but it isn't grammatically _incorrect._ One of them uses commas in a way I wouldn't, etc., etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with rogermue. B is wrong.

Wrong:

B) "I am sorry, but **`I am not understanding`** what you are trying to say."

Correct:

B) "I am sorry, but **`I do not understand`** what you are trying to say."

The question would be **`Do you understand me?`** (not "Are you understanding me?")

Answer (score 4):

Sentence B is not correct: It should be: I don't understand what you are saying.
There are some verbs in English that are not used with progressive forms. See your grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the deficient punctuation pointed out by Tyler James Young, all of these sentences are acceptable formal English.

However, I think it very likely that your teacher wants you to identify sentence C as incorrect. As Tyler James Young (again) points out, use of *understand* in the present progressive is unusual, and you have probably been taught that it is ungrammatical. That‘s not true; but it is a ‘baby rule’ which is taught in the earlier stages of English instruction to keep students from using this construction until they have a sound understanding of when they can and when they cannot use it.

The use of progressive constructions with *stative* verbs like *understand*, *know*, *love*, and *be* has been discussed frequently on ELL; and in fact their use specifically with *understand* is addressed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/350/32).

Answer (score 0):

B is not correct as it is only acceptable to say I don't understand what you are trying to say.